# How to make serialization of a form class rather than id to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, serialization

How does one make serialization work with an element gotten by class rather than ID? my var data only becomes an empty string. Thanks.

```
AddDsr: function() {
            var data = $('DsrEditForm[0]').serialize();
            alert(data);

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ValidateEditDsr.php/ValidateEditDsr',
            datatype: 'text',
            data: ({formData: data}),
            success: function(answer) {
                alert(answer);
                console.log(answer);
            },
            error: function(answer) {
                console.log(answer);
            }
              });
        }
```

Update: In answer to a comment, here is what DsrEditForm is:

```
CreateNewDsrForm: function() {
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.className = 'DsrEditForm';
    f.name = 'DsrEditForm';
    document.getElementById('DsrEditContainer').appendChild(f);
```

Comment: what is `DsrEditForm[0]`

Comment: There, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DsrEditForm` is the class name user [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
var data = $('.DsrEditForm').serialize();
```

Comment: While this works, won't I have a problem when I'll have multiple instances of DsrEditForm?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron then then you should decide which one has to be submitted... it has to be logic based on your business requirements...

Comment: How? If $('.DsrEditForm') refers to all instance of that class, and $('.DsrEditForm')[i] won't work, how can I send a specific instance of $('.DsrEditForm')?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron how do you know which form has to be submitted... if the form at index 0 has to be submitted then you can use `$('.DsrEditForm').eq(0).serialize();` or `$('.DsrEditForm:eq(0)').serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
$.post( "ValidateEditDsr.php/ValidateEditDsr", $('DsrEditForm[0]').serialize())
.done(function(answer){
  console.log(answer);
})
.fail(function(answer){
  console.log(answer);
});
```